# How to get the fair value for an option with variable strike?

Tags: options, option-pricing

I'm dealing with a plain vanilla written put but my strike is linked to this formula:

$$K=(7 \cdot EBITDA\cdot Net Debt)\cdot  [\%P]$$

where

EBITDA = EBITDA of the company as of the last closed and audited accounts prior to the put exercise notice and the resulting EBITDA will be multiplied by 7

Net Debt = Net debt of the company as of the last closed and audited accounts prior to the put option exercise notice

%P = percentage interest of the minority shareholders at the date of exercise of the put option right

Comment: Jeepers, this looks complicated. What a mess.

Comment: With fair value, do you also want to model what the strike will look like? In that case, good luck. What's the purpose of this?

Answer (score 3):

You need a corporate finance type analysis for this. I am assuming you are valuing that option for a PE company or something of that sort.

Create scenarios for the company (revenue, cost, margins, debt, etc). Make several scenarios: agressive, benchmark, downside, etc. Value with discounted cashflows (including the option).

Comment: I agree with this. Risk neutral pricing would do more damage than good here

Comment: @phdstudent, I have some questions unrelated to this thread that I am struggling with. As a go-to expert on asset pricing, would you mind taking a look? Two of them have [bounties](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Bounties) on them.

Comment: @RichardHardy, seems like Kevin got it and I do not see an issue with his argument.

Comment: @phdstudent, yes, thank you. I have a few related questions that are linked in the comment to the bountied post. I would much appreciate your help with them, too!